# How to access elements from an NSObject in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, local-storage, nsobject

I've set some variables as an Object

```
import UIKit
class SpeedTestResult: NSObject {
    var testTime: NSDate?
}
```

Then in the controller I set this object and pass it to a class to store it:

```
testResult.testTime = NSDate()
SpeedTestManager().addTestResult(testResult)
```

I need to store this object and then access the elements within in a view later, This is what I have:

```
import Foundation
class SpeedTestManager : NSObject {
    var testResultArray = [NSObject]()
    func addTestResult(testResult: NSObject) {
        testResultArray.append(testResult)
        print("Printing testResultArray: \(testResultArray)")

    }
}
```

But when I try to print the the object I just get

```
Printing testResultArray: [<ProjectName.SpeedTestResult: 0x127b85e50>]
```

How do I access elements within the object and store this object and retrieve it for later use in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TestResult : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    var testTime: NSDate?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    @objc required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.testTime = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("testTime") as? NSDate
    }

    @objc func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
        encoder.encodeObject(self.testTime, forKey: "testTime")
    }

    @objc static func supportsSecureCoding() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var description: String {
        return String.init(format: "TestResult: %@", self.testTime ?? "null")
    }
}

class SpeedTestManager : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    var testResultArray = [NSObject]()

    func addTestResult(testResult: NSObject) {
        testResultArray.append(testResult)
        print("Printing testResultArray: \(testResultArray)")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    @objc func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
        encoder.encodeObject(self.testResultArray, forKey: "testResultArray")
    }

    @objc required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.testResultArray = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("testResultArray") as! [NSObject]
    }

    @objc static func supportsSecureCoding() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var description: String {
        return String.init(format: "SpeedManager: [%@]", self.testResultArray.map({"\($0)"}).joinWithSeparator(","))
    }
}

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let testResult = TestResult()
            testResult.testTime = NSDate()

        let speedManager = SpeedTestManager()
            speedManager.addTestResult(testResult)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(speedManager), forKey: "speedManager")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        if let archivedSpeedManager = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("speedManager") as? NSData {
            let unarchivedSpeedManager = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedSpeedManager)
            print("SpeedManager: \(unarchivedSpeedManager ?? "null")")
        }
        else {
            print("Failed to unarchive speed manager")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it:

```
    import Foundation

    class SpeedTestResult: NSObject {
        var testTime: NSDate?
    }

    class SpeedTestManager : NSObject {
        var testResultArray = [NSObject]()
        func addTestResult(testResult: NSObject) {
            testResultArray.append(testResult)
            for result in testResultArray {
//  This will crash if result is not a SpeedTestResult.
//                print((result as! SpeedTestResult).testTime)
//  This is better:
               if let timeResult = result as? SpeedTestResult
               {
                   print(timeResult.testTime)
               }
               else 
               {
                   print("Not time type...")
               }
            }           
        }
    }

    var testResult = SpeedTestResult()
    testResult.testTime = NSDate()
    SpeedTestManager().addTestResult(testResult)
```

This addresses your specific question, but there are some other problems here:

- If you are going to store only `SpeedTestResult` instances in
  `testResultArray`, then why not make it of type
  `[SpeedTestResutl]()`?
- If you will store different types of tests in the array, then how do
  you find out which type of test an `NSObject` element represents? 
  There are ways...  In the above code we at least make sure we are not treating a wrong type of object as a `SpeedTestResult`.
- When you do `SpeedTestManager().addTestResult(testResult)`, you don't
  keep a reference to the `SpeedTestManager` instance.  The next time
  you make the same call, you will be creating a different
  `SpeedTestManager` instance.
- This is not really a problem, but `SpeedTestManager` does not have to
  be a sub-class of `NSObject`, unless you want to use it in
  Objective-C.
- You probably don't want to print the content of `testResultArray` in
  the `addTestResult()` method.  You could have other methods for
  accessing the array.

To add your test results to the same test manager, you could do:

```
let myTestManager = SpeedTestManager()
myTestManager.addTestResult(testResult)     
// create other test results and add them ...
```